# volumes of immersed spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S^2:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ and let $\varphi:S^2\to\mathbb{R}^6$ be the immersion $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x^2,y^2,z^2,\sqrt2 xy,\sqrt2 yz,\sqrt2 zx)$.

I'm trying to compute the Riemann metric induced by $\varphi$ from the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^6$, and the volume of $S^2$ given by the corresponding volume form.

---

To really understand this problem, I computed the lower dimensional case $\varphi:S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}\to\mathbb{R}^3,(x,y)\mapsto(x^2,y^2,\sqrt2 xy)$. The metric matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}2+2x^2&2xy\\ 2xy&2+2y^2\end{pmatrix}$ with determinant $=8$. So in this way, the volume (length) is $\sqrt\det\cdot2\pi=4\sqrt2\pi$.

However, if one could do it directly, the image of $\varphi$ is $(\cos^2t,\sin^2t,\sqrt2\cos t\sin t)$ and $$L=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(-2\cos t\sin t)^2+(-2\cos t\sin t)^2+(\cos^2 t-\sin^2 t)^2}dt=2\sqrt2\pi$$, different from the first one.

Question: Where are the places I had misunderstandings in the lower dimensional case? Is the first way of computing directly used in the original problem? You could trust my computations, I checked them several times.

Comment: Under the map $\phi$, one complete loop around the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ goes twice around the circle in the image in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is why your arc length calculation is twice what you expect.

Comment: Notice that with $x = \cos t$ and $y = \sin t$, 
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x^2 &= \cos^2 t = \tfrac12 \bigl( 1 + \cos 2t \bigr), \\
y^2 &= \sin^2 t = \tfrac12 \bigl( 1 - \cos 2t \bigr), \\
\sqrt{2}xy &= \sqrt{2} \cos t \sin t = \tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sin 2t,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
and each of those coordinate functions has period $\pi$.

Comment: This map is **not** an embedding: it is not even injective since $f(-p) = f(p)$.
This is a double cover of the projective plane $\Bbb RP^2$, which is itself embedded in $\Bbb R^6$. It is related to the [Veronese embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronese_surface).

Comment: @Didier I've changed the terms, please see the new edition. One only needs immersions to have the both notions, and this is an immersion.